# How do I return mocks within a mock function in jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, axios

I am trying to mock the `axios.create()` function which returns an instance of axios however with fewer methods. I want to mock this `create()` method by returning an object with each of these methods however I also wish to mock these methods using `jest.fn()` so I have tried something like this

```
axiosInst = {
    get: jest.fn(),
    post: jest.fn(),
    ...
}
axios.create = jest.fn(() => axiosInst)
```

However it's not working when I run my test code I get this 
`TypeError: Cannot read property post of undefined`

In my code `axiosInst.post()` is called so for some reason the mocked `axios.create()` is returning `undefined` which makes absolutely no sense.

I am also confused as to how exactly I would set the `mockReturnValue` on the `axiosInst`. What would be the exact syntax of setting the return value for a method on the instance before I run a test?

Answer (score 0):

Try like below to mock return value for any mock function:

```
axios.create = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
  get: jest.fn(),
  set: jest.fn()
});
```

Also, you can set a resolved promise as return value for `get` here, since we might need to test success/failure scenarios in the test case, like below:

```
  const mockPromise = new Promise(resolve => resolve(
    { /** some mock data here */ })
  );

  axios.create = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
    get: mockPromise,
    set: jest.fn()
  });
);
```